# Is there anyway to check inactive terminalEditors in when arg in keybindings.json in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, vscode-keybinding

I want to `createTerminalEditor` if there is no `terminalEditor` opened yet.

Note: I'm talking about `terminalEditor` and not `terminal`.

So, I'm looking for a `when` arg which says something like `editorAlreadyExists != terminalEditor`, just like there is `activeEditor` which aceepts string of `terminalEditor`.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Here is `activeEditor` example for reference, but I want to check if `terminalEditor` exists in all the already opened editors, not just a `activeEditor`.

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+`",
    "command": "workbench.action.createTerminalEditor",
    "when": "activeEditor != terminalEditor"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that there is a `when` clause for:

`terminalEditorFocus`: true/false

which doesn't look like it would help ***except*** for the fact that it isn't in the list (via `Developer: Inspect Context Keys`) at all when there is no terminal editor open.  So I thought maybe there was a keybinding `when` clause that could exploit this.  But I tried all kinds of thing, like whether it was null or undefined or the empty string or neither true nor false, etc.  but nothing worked.  I think if the key `terminalEditorFocus` doesn't exist, then nothing at all is delivered to the keybinding resolver and it always fails.

You could file an issue asking for a specific `terminalEditorExists` sort of `when` clause.

---

There will be another way.  There is a presently experimental api to access all the open tabs.  See [proposed api](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/vscode.proposed.d.ts).  So you could write an extension that checks all the open tabs and fires the `workbench.action.createTerminalEditor` command if none are a terminalEditor.  It works right now in the Insiders Build, but when it will go final I don't know - it seems pretty solid now.  Issue: [Tab Model API](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133532).

```js
const tabs = vscode.window.tabs;
const openTerminalEditor = tabs.some(tab => tab.viewId === 'terminalEditor');  // true/false
```

Then you could either set your own context key with `setContext` or run the command.